# How to pass list as a parameter in response.redirect

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Prob1:I have 2 lists which i want to access in the next page which i will be redirecting.
Current result,
 When i pass my result, in the url it shows the List data type.

`ex:System.Collections.Generic.List1[IDataEntities.ISearchResultsEntity]`

Prob2:I have  a method call in ajax post,I am able to navigate to the method but inside i have done response.redirect which fails saying "Threadabort exception"

Comment: What does your code look like for Prob1?  For Prob2, don't do a redirect in an ajax post.

Comment: is your main goal is to make your list be available in another controller

Comment: yeah i have to bind the data to a grid which resides in my redirected page.. I acheived it through sessions.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Session to hold your list as below

```
Session["mylist"] = list;
```

you can access it from next page, there are many other ways. please check this [link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-Pass-Data-Between-935838e4).

when you call `Response.Redirect` call it as below

```
Response.Redirect(url, false);
Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

but don't do Redirect on ajax call from server side, ones ajax call completed you can redirect from client side call.

on success ajax call back method

```
window.location = '[url to redirect]';
```

Comment: session property works.. Thanks.. But while redirecting in my second case,i need to send 2 lists?

Answer (score 2):

Prob 1: You need to comma-separate your list values. Need more info to give you exact code as  I have no idea if this is asp.net or asp.net mvc or something else. If, say, this is redirecting to another action in asp.net mvc your receiver action param needs to be a List and you redirect to /Receiver?param1=value1,value2,value3 ...

Hopefully that answers your question

Prob 2: Cant redirect from an ajax request. Need to return something special and handle it on the front-end.

Comment: IT is just plain asp.net.. N am doing ajax post from client side.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Prob1. Add a public property to current page with type `List<Class>`. On the next page (target page of redirect()), add prevoiusPageType tag in ASPX file. Now you can access Page.PreviousPage.ListToAccess.

Prob2. Add false as param for redirect like `Response.Redirect("<URL-of-target-page", false);`